# Django filter/update model form SQLite database is being ignored when passing a variable

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.2

I am trying to update the first name of the record with a user input value for id.

If I hardcode the id, the change happens.

But, if I pass the user input variable to it, it just ignores it.  No errors, but no change.

THIS CODE WORKS FINE:

```py
def edit_student_view(request):
    global epicenteridtoupdate
    epicenteridtoupdate = None
    form = EditStudentModelForm(request.GET or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit = False)
        epicenteridtoupdate = (EditStudentModelForm.GET.get())

        if obj.get() in request.session:
            epicenteridtoupdate = request.session[(obj.get())]

        form = EnrollmentModelForm()

    template_name = 'form.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    update = Student.objects.get(epicenterid__iexact='30350')
    update.studentfname ='New First Name'
    update.save()

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

HOWEVER, THIS CODE DOESN'T DO ANYTHING.  NO ERRORS, BUT NO CHANGE:

```py
def edit_student_view(request):
    global epicenteridtoupdate
    epicenteridtoupdate = None
    form = EditStudentModelForm(request.GET or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit = False)
        epicenteridtoupdate = (EditStudentModelForm.GET.get())

        if obj.get() in request.session:
            epicenteridtoupdate = request.session[(obj.get())]

        form = EnrollmentModelForm()

    template_name = 'form.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    update = Student.objects.get(epicenterid__iexact=epicenteridtoupdate)
    update.studentfname ='New First Name'
    update.save()

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Any help would be so much appreciated!

I have tried every possible way to write this filter, but it ignores the variable.

Comment: What does `EditStudentModelForm.GET.get()` do? My guess is it would always return `None`.

Comment: even when i change it to EditStudentModelForm.get() I have the exact same results.  It works fine if I hard code the id to use.  But, as soon as I pass that variable, nothing...

Comment: should i use an html form instead of a model form to grab the user's search value?

Comment: Rest of the code outside the `if form.is_valid():`, should be come up with inside the `if form.is_valid():` statement. You set the values to `update` statement after check form validation, `epicenteridtoupdate` value always be `None` if you didn't go to the `if form.is_valid():` statement. Better if you can provide the error which you get.

Comment: Hi Kushan, it doesn't cause any error at all.  It simply does not do any updating when I insert the variable name in place of a hardcoded change:  ie:  (epicenterid='1234') will alter that record, but (epicenteid=epicenteridtoupdate) does nothing.  No errors, it's just like it can't see the variable value that was just set in the form.